# Implementing Aggregate Report in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

Here is a Smaller version of a large table I have.  This table stores an answer to a Question where the dropdown list offers options {P,C,U}

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IssuesSummary](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CaseNumberFK] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [TeenPregnancyEarlyTeen17andunderFK] [int] NULL,
    [TeenPregnancyLateTeen18And19FK] [int] NULL,
    [PregnancyOver35yrsFK] [int] NULL,
    [CordProblemFK] [int] NULL,
    [PlacentalAbruptionFK] [int] NULL
....
```

The client is asking for a report in the format below.  For each field in the database I am to provide a total (N) for answer of P, C, and U and then the percentage for the values next to it for that field.

```
P       C       U       
N   %   N   %   N   %   

0   0   10  20  0   0   Pregnancy Over 35yrs

5   10  0   0   0   0   Cord Problem
```

My question is: Is there something already built into SSRS to help me do this.  This is not exactly a cross-tab case.  My default solution is to create a stored procedure that can return the data in this tabular format and then just associate a table in the report with the dataset.  I wanted to see if there is a better way of doing this utilizing tools already within the reproting features within Visual Studio 2013.

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide

Comment: What fields contains the value P/C/U? Or can all the foreign key fields contain this value?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways you can do this in SSRS.

One is among them and probably the simplest way to add a sub total for a group in the table.

lets say I am having a group say as 'project' and I can add a total field by right click in the textbox which will give me the total for the group.

You can see here the expression in the group total is too the same what you are using in the group. Let me know if this is helpful.

Thanks,
Sarat